# Subquery in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, t-sql

Say I have the following table:

table1

```
ID    DATE         TYPE
001   2017-08-01   50
002   2017-08-01   40
003   2017-08-01   40
001   2017-05-01   50
```

And I have another table
table2

```
ID   DATE          TYPE
001  2005-01-01    50
002  2010-10-11    30
```

And say I want to use a case statement that would pull data from another table using a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT 
   ID
  ,MAX(DATE)
  ,CASE WHEN TYPE = '50'
        THEN (
              SELECT MAX(DATE) 
              FROM table2 
              WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
              ELSE '10' END
             )
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Only problem is I can't use a subquery if I have a Group By:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

So what is a good alternative?

Comment: That's not your only problem.  max(date) will return a date data type.  10 is not a date data type.  A column can't be multiple data types.  but the error is becuase you have the else inside the ()'s when it needs to be outside for the case statement.

Comment: What if it were varchar? ie. '10'

Comment: varchar would work provided you cast both the date and the 10 to varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join instead :

```
SELECT t.id,MAX(t.date), COALESCE(s.max_date,DefaultDateHerE) as max_date_t2
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN(SELECT p.id,MAX(p.date) as max_date
          FROM Table2
          GROUP BY p.id) s
 ON(s.id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.id,COALESCE(s.max_date,DefaultDateHerE)
```

Comment: what do you mean 'DefaultDateHerE'?

Comment: What do you want to present if there is no match ? like the else part in your code (10) . It's just more logical to put a default date like : `01/01/1954`

Comment: Getting an error: `Column 'S.max_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is only part of the problem. The first issue is using the `TYPE` column all by itself in that `CASE` statement. Imagine you had this data:

```
ID   TYPE
 1     49
 2     50
 2     51
```

You're grouping on `ID` and then checking `TYPE` outside of the group. ID #1 would be fine, but what is the database supposed to do with ID #2? Should it match the case condition or not?

Now you and I both know from your sample data that this doesn't happen. In the `table1` sample data all the records in a group have the same `Type` value. But the database can't know that. There's no reason you couldn't update a record to have mixed `Type` values for a single `ID`, and so the database engine won't allow this.

You'll need to either include the `TYPE` column in the `GROUP BY` clause or use it with an aggregate function. If you can do the latter, that should sort of "pin down" the value for that record and also allow you use your sub query... if that's what you really want. You can probably do better with a JOIN or APPLY anyway.

Comment: Ugh, had a mistake in my sample data. This should make more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try **LEFT JOIN** and in "ON" statement add filter table2.Type = 50

```
SELECT table1.ID,
   max(table1.[DATE]) [table1.DATE],
   max(table2.[DATE]) [table2.DATE]
FROM (VALUES ('001','2017-08-01','50')
    ,('002','2017-08-01','40')
    ,('003','2017-08-01','40')
    ,('001','2017-05-01','50')
    ) table1([ID],[DATE],[TYPE])
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
        VALUES ('001','2005-01-01','50')
                ,('002','2010-10-11','30')
        ) table2([ID],[DATE],[TYPE]) ON table1.ID = table2.ID
        and table2.Type = 50
GROUP BY table1.ID
```